# Finding resolution of quantizer with both corrupted input noise and quantization noise

Tags: adc

I'm trying understand how to find the bits required to get a quantization noise of 32 dB from an input signal that is already containing some noise due to corruption.

If the input signal is already corrupted with an SNR of 35 dB and Vin = 1 VFS

- 35dB -> 1 V + 1 V (1/56.234) = **1.01778 V**

and for the quantization noise of 32dB

- 32dB -> 1.01778 V + 1.01778 V (1/39.81) = **1.0429 V**

To get the resolution of bits use V_LSB:

- V_LSB = V_Q(sqrt(12)) = 3.61
- 1/V_LSB = 2^N
- N = -1.852 bits

Obviously negative bits cannot be correct. What step of this process is incorrect?

Comment: "35dB -> 1V (1/56.234) = 1.01778V"  <- I have no idea what you are doing there.  Where do those numbers come from?

Comment: @user1850479 If you take 35dB and input it into a gain to voltage calculator it equates 35dB to a gain of 56.234, so I interpreted that as the input signal being 56.234x the noise voltage, thus 1/56.234 to get the additional noise added to the input signal voltage. I just edited those lines to make it a bit more clear

Comment: The edit makes your thinking a little more clear, but quantization noise does not add like that since it is a random value that can be positive or negative, whereas you're assuming it is positive only.  What does V_Q mean?  Where did you get the square root of 12?

Comment: @user1850479 V_Q is supposed to be the quantization noise and the sqrt of 12 comes from the quantization step equation listed at the top of this white paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/quantization-noise-power#:~:text=The%20mean%20squared%20quantization%20noise,600%20%CE%A9%20to%201000%20%CE%A9.

Comment: Q in that link is the quantization step size, in this case 1/(2^N), so you're mixing up your variables.  Most people would say that since there are 6dB of quantization noise per bit, quantization noise 32dB below peak requires 32/6 = 5.33 bits.  Is this the answer you're looking for?

Comment: @user1850479 Actually I think that is exactly what I'm looking for :). I also got 5 bits manually by assuming the input was 1VFS including the corrupted noise, calculating Vq = 0.025V from 32dB and solving from there

Comment: Great, if that is all you're looking for I'll type up a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying understand how to find the bits required to get a quantization noise of 32 dB from an input signal that is already containing some noise due to corruption.

Quantization noise is usually assumed to be independent of the input signal, so you can ignore everything else simply do 32 dB / 6dB per bit = 5.33 bits.